# Interpreting sp_BlitzCache: # Executions but since when?

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzcache

I'm getting started with [`sp_BlitzCache`](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/)  (which is amazing!) and trying to understand the results better. When does the `# Executions` count from? e.g. if it says 343 executions is that today, since server start, or what? I'm running it like this:

```
sp_blitzCache @MinutesBack = 1440, @sortOrder = 'query hash'
```

But the `# Executions` appears not to change based on the `@MinutesBack` parameter so I'm guessing it's since some fixed time period?

I'm using SQL 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scroll across to the right side of the results, and there's a "Created At" column. That column shows when the plan first went into the cache. In most cases, SQL Server tracks the execution count since that time - but there can be exceptions in some cases involving recompiles of a query.

The source is the execution_count column in [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).